# I have many problems which I cannot find fixes for online

Tags: texturing

I am new to blender, and I have been looking online at fixes for these problems for about 2 hours now, and none of them seem to work.

1. Colours do not show up in 3D view.(The preview works.)
2. Textures do not show up in 3D view. (The preview works.)
3. Trying to render my project mostly goes unresponsive, if it does work it leaves me with a black screen.
4. This isn't that bad of a problem, its just very annoying, but every time I go into the colour/textures tab, blender becomes unresponsive, until my fans get very loud then it responds, but when my fans go back to normal speed it once again becomes unresponsive. I have about a 5 second window to fiddle around with the textures/colours. This doesn't happen to anything else, apart from rendering.
   If it helps, I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.

What it looks like in 3D view:
[image: What it looks like in 3D view.]

The render:
[image: The render.]

Comment: hello, please share your file or at least a simplified version of your file, use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: about the black screen please check your camera position. why the texture wont show up might be you didn't pack it to blend file. hmm i dunno, i'm just guessing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Comment: Also use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

For your first two questions, your image shows that you're in solid view mode (1 on the image). 2 is Mateial preview mode and 3 is Rendered view. Click each in turn to see what they do.
[image]

Not sure what the problem is with your other questions, but you should generally ask one question at a time on this forum.